# Access data object in asyncData - Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I wonder if there is a way to access object properties as keys returned by asyncData()?

```
data() {
    return {
       bookmark_btn: {
        status: null,
        loading: false
      }
   }
}
```

I tried access data object properties like below but didn't work.

```
async asyncData(){
    let activity = await axios.get('data.json')
    return { bookmark_btn.status: activity.status}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, because `asyncData` is a server rendered method you can't directly access your components `data`.

Previous solution works but I don't think it's how things are intended to work with Nuxt and it's complicated (using a 3rd party lib Vuex and messing around context object).

According to the [API](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data), `asyncData` will be merged into your `data` after loading the client side, which means you will have access to the returning value object of your **page**.

This mean you can use it directly to change the state of your page when the server side finishes loading so you either use the reactivity of vue and use it directly or you use the value within the `mounted` property of your **page** which is the solution for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use new fetch method instead of asyncData present in  **Nuxt >= 2.12** . this fetch method can have data properties.

```
async fetch() {
    let activity = await axios.get('data.json')

    this.$set(this.bookmark_btn, 'status', activity.status)
}
```

Check out more in official docs https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/

Or to use old asyncData, remove data() from component as whatever asyncData will return, will append in data(). So you can try out this

```
  async asyncData() {
    let activity = await axios.get("data.json")
    return {
      bookmark_btn:{
        status: activity.status,
        loading: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: your answer is partially correct in this case. as my architecture and use case does not support fetch method.

Comment: Actually its an API, for the sake of example i used data.json

Answer (score 1):

if you put data in store can you easily git this data to asyncData function

```js
export default {
  state: () => ({
    posts: [],
    selectedPost: {},
    page:3
  }),
  mutations: {
    updatePosts(state, posts){
      state.posts = posts;
    },
    updateSelectedPost(state, post){
      state.selectedPost = post;
    }
  }
}
```

that was store file

```js
 asyncData({$axios , store }  ){
         return $axios.$get(`http://localhost:3001/data?_page=${store.state.page}&_limit=20`)
         .then( res =>{
           
                 store.commit("updatePosts", res);
          })
      },
```

that was index.vue file